# TypeScript Class Implements Interface with Union Type Field results in Error (2322)

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, types, frontend

I don't understand why the error 2322 is occurring.

Please examine the following code snippet:

```
interface Fish {
  alive: string | boolean;
}

class FishClass implements Fish {
  alive  = 'Yes'

  constructor() {
    // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
    this.alive = true; 
  }
}
```

The interface defines the union type for string | boolean.

Why is the type fixed when I assigned one of the two possible types to the field inside the class that implements the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite most people's expectations, class members are not [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) by the types they are declared to implement or extend.  An `extends` or `implements` declaration on a class has no effect whatsoever on the type of the class instance.  Instead, it just does a *check* of the class against the superclass or interface after the fact.  So if your class fails to implement or extend what you've declared it to, you'll get a compiler warning.  But when it comes to the resulting types, it will be the same as if you removed the `extends` or `implements` clause entirely.  No, nobody likes this.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#3667](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3667) for the original request to fix this, and there was an attempt at [microsoft/TypeScript#6118](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118) but it was eventually abandoned due to some problems with existing libraries; see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207).  There are several open issues about this, including [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082); if you want to see this addressed you might want to go to that issue and give it a , but for now we just have to live with the fact that `class Foo implements Bar {/*...*/}` has the same implications for the type of  `Foo` as `class Foo {/*...*/}` does.

---

In your case, that means `class FishClass implements Fish {/*...*/}` acts exactly like `class FishClass {/*...*/}` when it comes to how the members are inferred. Since the `alive` property is initialized with a `string` value of `"Yes"`, the compiler infers it to be of type `string`.  And later when you assign `true` to it, that's an error because you can't assign a `boolean` to a `string`.  Note that `string` is assignable to `string | boolean`, so the check on `FishClass implements Fish` succeeds; you are allowed to narrow properties of subtypes.

The right way to deal with this for now is to manually annotate the [field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) with the desired type:

```
class FishClass implements Fish {
   alive: string | boolean = 'Yes'; // okay

   constructor() {
      this.alive = true; // okay
   }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAM4AtkG8BQyRcANsAG4QBcyGYUoA5sgD7IBGA9pyRHCAG58AX3z4EJOBgxpMWAMKTpyYAFsADr1URwM9NjyFiZSjToMQzNlx58QyALzIA5AE0IGZwOQB6H8k4AazgATzEiZAROEHMAVwQwTigACgBKQwiIsCxMADpSChQneliIbz8A4LCI0WEgA)