# Understanding TS' type inferring/narrowing with combination of extends & implements

Tags: typescript, extends, instanceof, implements

I have the following example code

```
class B implements Error {
  name: string = '';
  message: string = '';
  // stack?: undefined | string;
}

function Foo(x: any) {
  if(x instanceof Error) {
    if(x instanceof B) {
      x.stack;  // works
    }
  }
}

abstract class C {
  someProp: number = 0;
}

class D extends C implements Error{
  name: string = '';
  message: string = '';
  // stack?: undefined | string
}

function Bar(x: any) {
  if(x instanceof Error) {
    if(x instanceof D) {
      x.stack // does not work: Property 'stack' does not exist on type 'D'.
    }
  }
}
```

I don't really understand why trying to access `stack` in `Bar(..)` fails but works in `Foo(..)`.

Why does `extends` make this fail for `Bar` after having narrowed to Error in the outer if?

Comment: This has nothing much to do with `extends` nor `implements`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzP7eN).  It's definitely a narrowing issue, though, having to do with an interesting type system unsoundness around optional properties.  Your `B` is not considered narrower than `Error` (that is `Error` is assignable to `B`), so narrowing to both `B` and `Error` results in `Error`, a common subtype.  But `D` has an extra property, so `D` is considered narrower than `Error`, so narrowing to both results in `D`.  Without optional property unsoundesses this wouldn't matter, but...

Comment: @jcalz could you please provide an answer?

Comment: ... with them, you see weirdness, since `Error` knows about `stack` but `D` does not.  Does this fully address your question or am I missing something? I can write up a full answer if it meets your needs. Otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I'll do so if OP confirms, otherwise I run the significant risk of writing up a full answer and then getting "lol no sorry" as a response for the effort

Comment: @jcalz do you know where this unsoundness comes from?
Is it something that can be inferred from the docs, too. Or only from the implementation, so it's pure coincidence that i stumbled across this?

Comment: TypeScript pretends that, for assignability purposes, an optional property is assignable to an unmentioned property.  So the type `{x?: 0, y: 1}` is mutually assignable to `{y: 1}`, and `{x?:2, y: 1}` is also mutually assignable to `{y: 1}`.  But `{x?:0, y: 1}` is mutually *unassignable* to `{x?:2, y: 1}`.  It's unsound.  So depending on the order of operations you can make the compiler do funny things with optional property assignability.

Comment: "Is it something that can be inferred from the docs, too. Or only from the implementation, so it's pure coincidence that i stumbled across this?" It's mentioned a bit [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#optional-parameters-and-rest-parameters) and  in the GitHub repo issues ([ms/TS#47499](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47499) plus links from there), which they consider part of the "docs" but it's not laid out nicely

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, So if you like to create an answer, i'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: Okay I'll write it up when I get a chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things going on here, but I'd say the primary issue is that TypeScript's type system is [not completely *sound*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), in particular around [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).

TypeScript allows you to assign an object without a known property to a type with that property as an *optional* property.  So `{x: string}` is assignable to `{x: string, y?: number}`.  This is very convenient, but it's not sound, since all the compiler really knows about a value of type `{x: string}` is that it has an `x` property of type `string`.  It doesn't know *anything* about the `y` property, so it can't know that the `y` property is a `number` or missing.  It's a [known unsoundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#optional-parameters-and-rest-parameters) mentioned in the TypeScript GitHub repository issues list in several places, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#47499](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47499).  Again, it's convenient; imagine if you wrote `const z = {x: "hello"}` and then *couldn't* assign `z` to a variable of type `{x: string, y?: number}`.  That would be safe, but so annoying to use that people would be unhappy.

TypeScript also allows the (relatively) *sound* operation of assigning an object with a known property (optional or otherwise) to a type without that known property. So `{x: string, y?: number}` is assignable to `{x: string}`.  Object types are open, not sealed.  (See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69666350/2887218) for more information.)

Combining those means that types with optional properties are *mutually assignable* with types without known properties, so when the compiler narrows or widens one type to another, it can end up forgetting about optional properties depending on the exact set of operations and the order.

---

Your example code is equivalent to

```
class B {
    name: string = '';
    message: string = '';
}

function Foo(x: any) {
    if (x instanceof Error) {
        if (x instanceof B) {
            x.stack;  // okay
        }
    }
}

class D {
    someProp: number = 0;
    name: string = '';
    message: string = '';
}

function Bar(x: any) {
    if (x instanceof Error) {
        if (x instanceof D) {
            x.stack // error!
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `implements` clauses on your classes have no effect on their instance types (see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70038461/2887218) for more information), so you might as well remove `implements Error` as it doesn't do anything.  Similarly the `extends C` part of your class only serves to have `D` inherit the `someProp` property, so you might as well define it directly in `D`.

The issue here is that `Error` is considered to be assignable to `B`, even though it's missing `Error`'s optional `stack` property.  When you narrow `x` from `Error` to `B`, the compiler doesn't see it as needing to narrow at all.  The type stays `Error`, and thus `x` has an optional `stack` property.

On the other hand, `Error` is not assignable to `D`, since `D` has a required `someProp` property that `Error` doesn't necessarily have. `D` is considered to be narrower than `Error`.  When you narrow `x` from `Error` to `D`, the compiler dutifully narrows to `D`.  And *now* `x` has no known `stack` property, because `D` doesn't.

So there you go.  TypeScript has some unsoundness that's allowed for convenience, and effects of this unsoundness can crop up in some strange places.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBC0G8BQ1XQHZgLYFMBc0EALgE4CW6A5tALzQDk9A3CmrlGJfoaRdXYxYBfJEgBmAV3TAiZAPbpoAMTlyAFAA8CYdAE8AlIlaoyY6JugViO4DjlmAoiRJySh5Gk+WzFq0Rt2ZrDuxl6eGgB01sAA1kyoAPQJ0ADurjEQoZ4i2UgiSKCQMAAiRp4QcrgACi4ADgToElgARjgktNAADCyemLgExORUHYKh7BCc3IN8I8x5opLSsgpwYCSa2nohnqbmGpbo1tKB0E4ubmVh3nsHR7b20MXbV+FR-rHQSdAAJnI4MOg5ERUukCDU5LU2kRdAxojF6D8-gCgdAcBoyMRoCtoZCGMV6BEsmgcsS8kA)