# How to use a object to feed a model class

Tags: typescript, class, interface

A get a large object from a API response, and I want to use this object to feed a class that represents a model where I can have some methods to analyse it.

For example:

This is the API response object interface

```js
interface User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    age: number;
    isActive: boolean;
    address?: {
        street: string;
        city: string;
        postalCode: string;
    };
    roles: string[];
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

I already know I could do something like

```js
class UserModel {
    private user: User;

    constructor(user: User) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    getUserId(): void {
        return this.user.id
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

But in this case I will always have to use `this.user.[something]`

Altenatively I got this other way

```js
class UserClass {
    private readonly id: number;
    private readonly username: string;
    private readonly email: string;
    private readonly age: number;
    private readonly isActive: boolean;
    private readonly address?: {
        street: string;
        city: string;
        postalCode: string;
    };
    private readonly roles: string[];
    private readonly createdAt: Date;
    private readonly updatedAt?: Date;

    constructor(user: User) {
        const {
            id,
            username,
            email,
            age,
            isActive,
            address,
            roles,
            createdAt,
            updatedAt
        } = user;

        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.address = address;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

     getUser(): void {
        return this.id
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Which solves the problem to have to use a extra property, here is fine to use `this[something]`, but it's too polluted.

I was wondering if there is a way when I get class cleaner like first example, but props not grouped like second one

Comment: Does it have to be `private`?  You can't automatically generate `private` properties.  If you need that, then the answer is probably "you can't do this without redundancy".  If you don't need that, then this looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69291358/2887218) and the answer there applies here too.  Does that fully address the question?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz It's pretty much what I needed, thank you very much. Just one question, I played this code in playground and remove do `implements MyInterface` and nothing changed. Did I miss anything?

Comment: `implements` clauses have no effect on types, they just *check* things and issue warnings if they check fails.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70038461/2887218 for example